# Disconnectedness in Rigid Analytic Geometry: a technical question

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rigid-analytic-geometry

I have a technical question in rigid analytic geometry, in the sense of Tate.

Let $B$ be an affinoid space over $\mathbb Q_p$, $Z$ a rigid analytic variety with a flat surjective map $f:Z \rightarrow B$. Let $Y$ be an open affinoid subset of $Z$, such that the map $f_{|Y}$ is finite and surjective over $B$.

> Is it true that $Y$ is disconnected from its complement in $Z$ (that is that there is a function $e$ in $\mathcal O(Z)$ such that $e^2=e$ and $Y$ is the locus of $e=1$)?

This is my understanding (but I may be missing some hypothesis) of what Buzzard asserts in footnote 2 page 26 (section 4) of its paper Eigenvarieties. (In the situation consider by Buzzard, $Z$ is a closed subvariety of $B \times \bf A^1$ ($\bf A^1$ the rigid affine line) and $Y$ is the subset of $z \in Z$ such that $| pr_2(z) | \leq 1$, where $pr_2: Z \rightarrow \bf A^1$ is the second projection -- but I do not think that helps.)

Buzzard attributes the idea to Grosse-Klönne and just says "one can use 9.6.3/3 and 9.5.3/5 of [BGR] to prove that $Y \rightarrow Z$ is both an open and a closed immersion". Here [BGR] is naturally the book Non-Archimedean Analysis by Bosch, Güntzer and Remmert. Unfortunately, I am not able to understand how the results of [BGR] imply the desired assertions. Thanks for anyone who can help me understand this argument.

Comment: Can we use the valuative criterion to show that the inclusion $Y\to Z$ is proper?

Comment: @WilleLiou: There is a valuative criterion in the context of adic spaces, but that is heavy overkill.  Even for schemes, using the valuative criterion is much too heavy for this situation: properness can be deduced by a standard graph argument (which works for rigid-analytic spaces too). This will be in my next comment.

Comment: You should assume $f$ is separated. Then it goes as for schemes. Note that $j:Y\hookrightarrow Z$ is the composition of the graph $Y \to Y\times_B Z$ that is a closed immersion (base change of $\Delta_{Z/B}$) and the projection $Y\times_B Z\to Z$ that is finite, so $j$ is finite since a closed subspace of finite is finite. So $j(Y)$ is the support of a coherent sheaf and hence is Zariski-closed (no need for any serious theorems about properness!). But $j(Y)$ is admissible open, so the coherent radical ideal $J$ defining it satisfies $J^2=J$. Now do commutative algebra on affinoid opens.

Comment: If you only knew $Y$ is $B$-proper, rather than actually $B$-finite, the same conclusion works by using that closed subspace of proper is proper (immediate from definitions; don't need preservation of general properness under composition, which lies much deeper) and using [BGR, 9.6.3/3] to get that $j(Y)$ is Zariski-closed.